# Async method returning undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to do an async call to return a result. The result was successful but no matter how i try to do it - the caller keeps seeing undefined. Could you help me see what i am doing wrong.

Çaller: (always getting undefined)

```
 groups.forEach(async group =>{
        let foundShares =  await group.getShares();
        console.log("found shares ", foundShares)
```

Target: (from my logs the returnShares is pushed and populated)

````
UserTaskGroupsSchema.methods.getShares =  async function () {

console.log("start hasshares")
let returnShares = [];
let users = this._team.users;

  users.forEach( user=>{
    if (user.shares)
    {
       user.shares.forEach( share=>{
          if (share.groupId.toString() === this._id.toString()){
            console.log("found share with groupid ")
             returnShares.push(share);
          }
      });
    }
    console.log("Returning returnshares ", returnShares)
    return returnShares;
  })
}```
````

Comment: Move `return returnShares` outside of forEach

Comment: why is `UserTaskGroupsSchema.methods.getShares` async? there's nothing async about it at all

Comment: by the way ... your `getShares` function can be written `return this._team.users.filter(user => user.shares).flatmap(user => user.shares.filter(share => share.groupId.toString() === this._id.toString()));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article, and see why await inside a forEach doesn't work.
https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

Replace the forEach with:

```
for (const group of groups) {
    let foundShares =  await group.getShares();
    console.log("found shares ", foundShares)
}
```

Comment: that's not the only problem, since `group.getShares()` still returns a Promise that resolves to undefined

Comment: i also did the fix that nithin above suggested. worked

Comment: why is `UserTaskGroupsSchema.methods.getShares` async when there's nothing async about it?

Comment: considering there's no need for `getShares` to be async, there's no need to change the `forEach` into a `for...of` - making this answer even more redundant